# How to get file path in a Ionic 1

Tags: ionic-framework

I am facing issue during file uploding in Ionic 1. I am not getting exact file path instead of image url I am getting very long url so please check and help me.

```
$scope.selectPhoto = function(){
        var options = {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                    targetWidth: 400,
                   targetHeight: 500
        };

              $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(
                function(imageData) {
                        $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Image Selected...', duration:1000});
                            $scope.imageURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                            $scope.imgeCaptured = imageData;

                             $scope.imge = {
                              "action":"create",
                              "id":"",
                              "plantId":$localStorage.plantid,
                              "machineId":"",
                              "attachmentPath":$scope.imgeCaptured
                            }
                             alert ($scope.imge);   
                },
                function(err){
                    $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Errore in Image Selection...', duration:500});
                })                    
    }
```

Comment: could you please post the output of `console.log(imageData)` ?

Answer (score 0):

to capture or pick image

```
 $scope.loadImage = function() {
  var options = {
    title: 'Select Image Source',
    buttonLabels: ['Load from Library', 'Use Camera'],
    addCancelButtonWithLabel: 'Cancel',
    androidEnableCancelButton : true,
  };
  $cordovaActionSheet.show(options).then(function(btnIndex) {
    var type = null;
    if (btnIndex === 1) {
      type = Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
    } else if (btnIndex === 2) {
      type = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
    }
    if (type !== null) {
      $scope.selectPicture(type);
    }
  });
};
```

this code will be called on selection and image moved to local app directory and image name will be obtained here

```
$scope.selectPicture = function(sourceType) {
  var options = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: sourceType,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
  };

  $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imagePath) {
    // Grab the file name of the photo in the temporary directory
    var currentName = imagePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

    //Create a new name for the photo
    var d = new Date(),
    n = d.getTime(),
    newFileName =  n + ".jpg";

    // If you are trying to load image from the gallery on Android we need special treatment!
    if ($cordovaDevice.getPlatform() == 'Android' && sourceType === Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY) {
      window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(imagePath, function(entry) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(entry, success, fail);
        function fail(e) {
          console.error('Error: ', e);
        }

        function success(fileEntry) {
          var namePath = fileEntry.nativeURL.substr(0, fileEntry.nativeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          // Only copy because of access rights
          $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, fileEntry.name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success){
            $scope.image = newFileName;
          }, function(error){
            $scope.showAlert('Error', error.exception);
          });
        };
      }
    );
    } else {
      var namePath = imagePath.substr(0, imagePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      // Move the file to permanent storage
      $cordovaFile.moveFile(namePath, currentName, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newFileName).then(function(success){
        $scope.image = newFileName;
      }, function(error){
        $scope.showAlert('Error', error.exception);
      });
    }
  },
  function(err){
    // Not always an error, maybe cancel was pressed...
  })
};
```

this method will give you the image path

```
// Returns the local path inside the app for an image
$scope.pathForImage = function(image) {
  if (image === null) {
    return '';
  } else {
    return cordova.file.dataDirectory + image;
  }
};
```

for more details check this [link](https://devdactic.com/ionic-image-upload-php/)